# Combine information from hi-resolution time series with another with daily information

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I have measurement data with - say - roughly 1 minute resolution, but irregular.

```
timeSeries
  time                signal
1 2015-03-30 00:00:00   17.3
2 2015-03-30 00:01:00   16.2
3 2015-03-30 00:02:01   18.4
4 2015-03-30 00:04:03   17.7
```

In a second data frame, I have daily information.

```
dailyInfo
  firstEvent          yesterday
1 2015-03-28 17:01:43 2015-03-27 15:25:51
2 2015-03-29 17:04:55 2015-03-28 17:01:43
3 2015-03-30 16:59:03 2015-03-29 17:04:55
```

The `dailyInfo$firstEvent` are my boundaries. I want to do something like

```
timeSeries %>% 
  group_by(between(time, dailyInfo$yesterday, dailyInfo$firstEvent))
```

In the tutorials, the information is always already present within the one data frame already (e.g. `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% ...`).

My workaround is to count the number of rows that are between each set of boundaries, then replicate the `firstEvent`-entry that often, concatenate and put the resulting vector into the `timeSeries` as a new column.

This is not very elegant, so maybe someone can help me how to use dplyr for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut`

```
timeSeries %>%
    mutate(interval = cut(time, dailyInfo$firstEvent)) %>%
    group_by(interval)
```

Or calculate the intervals directly in `group_by`

```
timeSeries %>%
    group_by(interval = cut(time, dailyInfo$firstEvent))

                 time signal            interval
1 2015-03-30 00:00:00   17.3 2015-03-29 17:04:55
2 2015-03-30 00:01:00   16.2 2015-03-29 17:04:55
3 2015-03-30 00:02:01   18.4 2015-03-29 17:04:55
4 2015-03-30 00:04:03   17.7 2015-03-29 17:04:55
```